# how to call synchronous web service call in xamarin forms?

Tags: web-services, xamarin, synchronous, xamarin.forms

I am creating an application in xamarin forms which needs synchronous web service call. But only GetAsync is available in xamarin forms. can anyone please explain me how to call synchronous web service call in xamarin forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```cs
public Webservice() { }
public Home GetHome()
{
    string strpost = "";
    var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(" xyz ");
    var response = client.PostAsync(new Uri(" xyz "), str).Result;
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Home>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    Home home = new Home();
    if (!Equals(result, null))
    {
        home = result;
        return home;
    }
}
```

Refer: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/43397/how-to-call-synchronous-webservice

Comment: Hi, do you have any idea that my web service call is taking much time to execute.

Comment: @gunas, It better you use async - await Methods. Or the perfect way is to call your web service little bit early.